# ListView/Activity within other View

Tags: android, arraylist

I'm getting a bit confused here as I'm trying to create a ListView displaying information from an arrayList within another layout.

I've created a ListActivity that works the way I want it to:

```
public class AndroidExample_ListViewActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Object test;
String[] lv_arr;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

ArrayList listTODO = PrepareList();
lv_arr = (String[]) listTODO.toArray(new String[0]);

ListView lv = getListView();

setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, (R.layout.list_item), lv_arr));
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
}
```

It uses the following layout:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="100px"
android:layout_marginTop="5px"
android:layout_marginBottom="50px"
android:paddingBottom="10px"
android:textSize="16sp"
android:background="@drawable/button1"
 >
</TextView>
```

The thing is that I want to be able to put this entire ListActivity into another Activity (my MainActivity). Bascially I would like to place this Activity (or rather the displayed ArrayList) within a RelativeLayout where I can place other elements as well. I'm just a bit lost on how do to it.

Comment: Can you describe more precisely what you want to achieve (the layout) in terms that you understand?

Answer (score 0):

Make your main.xml like:

```
<Layout>  
 <ListView>   
  ......... 
  </Listview> 
</Layout>
```

Make your class extend Activity (and not ListActivity)   implement OnItemClickListener..
And simply do this in java file..

```
ListView lv1= (ListView)findViewById(R.id.List);
lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,items));
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

Accept if it helps..